# File read is happening before file write in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, es6-promise, fs

I have  fs.writeFileSync and fs.readFile operation for my app to work. I have put both these operations under promise. I process other statements only after these promises are resolved. 
What I have observed is read is happening before write has completed

Here is my code snippet

To illustrate the above problem I have created a code snippet that writes random number to a file and later it will read file. If the file content is same as latest generated random number. Then read and write is synchronized.

**file.js**

```
   let fs = require('fs');
   let fileContent;
   let randomNumbers = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
   function test (filepath) {

      (async () => {

         await writefile(filepath);
         param = await readfile(filepath);
         console.log(param);
      }) ();
    }

    function writefile(filepath) {
       let promise;
       promise = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {

          fs.appendFileSync(randomNumbers,filepath);
       })  
       return promise;
    }

    function readfile(filepath) {
       let promise;
       promise = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
          fileContent = fs.readFileSync(filepath);
          if(  fileContent == randomNumbers ) {
            console.log("file read and write is synchronized");
          } else {
             console.log("file read and write is not synchronized");
          }
       })  
       return promise;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're misusing your Promise objects.

```
 await writeFile(path)
```

won't complete until you call the `resolve()` method in your Promise function.

Maybe you should change `writeFile()` function to look like this, and make a similar change to `readFile()`.

```
function writefile(filepath) {
   return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      fs.appendFileSync(randomNumbers,filepath);
      resolve()
   }) 
}
```

But, it has to be said, the sync functions in `fs` get rid of the need for promises. So you could do this just as easily.

```
function test (filepath) {
      fs.appendFileSync(randomNumbers,filepath);
      fileContent = fs.readFileSync(filepath);
      console.log(fileContent);
 }
```

Or you could wrap the async functions in promises, like this:

```
function writefile(filepath) {
   return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      fs.appendFile(randomNumbers,filepath, (err, result) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        else resolve(result);
      });
   })  
}
```

That's called *promisifying* the function.